# У меня задача - произведение элементов в каждом столбце под главной диагональю матрицы.

Tags: c, массивы

ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА, у меня задача `fi (aij)` - произведение элементов в каждом столбце под главной диагональю матрицы. `F (fi (aij))` - среднее арифметическое значение `fi (aij)`. Где у меня ошибка?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define n 5

void sort(int a[n][n]);

void dob (int d[n-1],int a[n][n])
{
    int i,j;
    d=1;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if (i>j)
            {
                d=d+a[i][j];
                printf("%d", d);
            }
        }
    }
    {
        double ser,s;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            s=0;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            s=s+d[i];
        ser=s/(n-1);
        printf("\n Seredne aryfmetychne=%lf",ser);
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int a[n][n];
    int d[i];
    system("cls");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%d", & a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    printf("Old array :\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
            printf("%5d", a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    sort(a);
    printf("New array :\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%5d", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    dob(d,a);
}

void sort(int a[n][n])
{
    int i, k, j, c;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(k = n-1; k>=0; k--)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                if(a[i][j] < a[i][j+1])
                {
                    c = a[i][j];
                    a[i][j] = a[i][j+1];
                    a[i][j+1] =c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А где у вас ошибка? Не компилируется, или резултат не тот? Добуток - это что?

Comment: добуток - произведение,,,,не могу разобраться что не так ....программа матрицу сортирует но не считает

Comment: Но програма же что то выдаёт или она  только в уме считает?

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, согласно стандарту языка C функция `main` без параметров должна быть объявлена как

```
int main( void )
```

У вас не инициализирована переменная `i` в начале программы, а потому следующее объявление массива не корректно

```
 int i,j,k;
 int a[n][n];
 int d[i];
 ^^^^^^^^
```

Почему бы вам его не определить как

```
 int d[n-1];
```

Еще лучше его определить, как имеющий тип `long long int`, потому что произведение целых чисел может не уместиться в объекте типа `int`

```
 long long int d[n-1];
```

сама функция произведения элементов в столбцах под главной диагональю может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void dob ( const int a[n][n], long long int d[n-1] )
{
    size_t k = 0;
    for ( size_t col = 0; col < n; col++ )
    {
        if ( col + 1 < n )
        {
            long long int result = 1;
            for ( size_t row = col + 1; row < n; row++ )
            {
                result *= a[row][col];
            }

            d[k++] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно вызов функции будет следующим

```
dob( a, d );
```

Всякий вывод на консоль результатов работы функции следует вынести из функции и поместить в `main`,